# Not getting props in react component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm not getting props in my Nav component. Odd thing is, 'this.props.history.push' is working in my other components.

The same function is working in my other components, but when I try to call the push function, I'm getting 'err in logout TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'. The 'this.props' object is logging as '{}'.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
import React from 'react'

import logo from 'logo.png'

import css from './Nav.module.scss'

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import axios from 'axios'

class Nav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: false
    }
    console.log(this.props)
  }

  _handleLogout = () => {
    // const self = this
    console.log(this.props)
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/logout', {
      withCredentials: true
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      console.log('logout')
      if (Cookies.get('sid') === undefined) {
        this.props.history.push('/')
      }
      console.log(this.props)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('err in logout', err)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={css.nav}>
        <div className={css.leftPart}>
          <Link to="/">
            <div className={css.brandicon}>
              <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />
            </div>
            <div className={css.brandname}>
              somebrand
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className={css.rightPart}>
          {
            Cookies.get('sid') === undefined ?
              <Link to="/login">
                <div className={css.loginButton}>
                  Login
                </div>
              </Link>
              :
              <div className={css.logoutButton} onClick={this._handleLogout}>
                Logout
              </div>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Nav
```

My Nav component is only referenced once in my Layout component:

```
import React from 'react'

import Nav from 'components/Nav/Nav'

import css from './BasicLayout.module.scss'

class Basic extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={css.page}>
        <Nav />
        <div className={css.content}>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Basic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`history` and `location` are special `props` injected by React Router's HOC `withRouter`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
class Nav extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const { history, location } = this.props
        return <div>{`I'm at ${location.pathname}`}</div>
    }
}
export default withRouter(Nav)
```

It works for `functional components` as well

```
export const Component = withRouter(({ history, location })) =>(
    <div>{`I'm at ${location.pathname}`}</div>
)
```